# How to remove part of a path and start from a certain part

Tags: c#

I have a path as follows here and user can pick any path they want but I need to trim down the path to something like this

full path = `D:\steam\steamapps\common\Call of Duty Black Ops III\xanim_export\elfenliedtopfan5_anims\pubg\m1911`

where I need to start.

`elfenliedtopfan5_anims\pubg\m1911`

Because the program I am writing to already has 
`D:\steam\steamapps\common\Call of Duty Black Ops III\xanim_export` included. So I just need whatever is after `xanim_export`.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Look at `IndexOf` to determine the location then use `Substring`.

Comment: It would really help if you posted [code that shows what you are writing](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please [attempt to solve the problem yourself](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) and show us what you've tried.

Comment: `D:\steam\steamapps\common\Call of Duty Black Ops III\xanim_export` could change right? if not you can just use `Replace` and replace it to an empty string but I believe that first part is variable.

Comment: First, you're going to need to get canonicalized versions of both paths (same slashes, same case) then check if the full path name (canonicalized) `StartsWith` the canonicalized root path. If it does, use `Substring` to strip the root path length from the original (non-canonicalized) full path

Comment: Look into `System.IO.Path` object and the methods like `.GetDirectoryName()`. The remove the last part and repeat.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This will give you the substring using the xanim_export\ as the starting .

```
    var key = @"xanim_export\";
    var path = @"D:\steam\steamapps\common\Call of Duty Black Ops III\xanim_export\elfenliedtopfan5_anims\pubg\m1911";
    var keyIndex = path.IndexOf(key);
    var newPath = path.Substring(keyIndex+key.Length);
```

Comment: thank you this worked perfectly marked as answer 

thank you evreyone for replying :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string full_path = @"D:\steam\steamapps\common\Call of Duty Black Ops III\xanim_export\elfenliedtopfan5_anims\pubg\m1911";

    var dir_1 = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(full_path);
    var dir_2 = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(dir_1);
    var common = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(dir_2);

    var specific = full_path.Substring(common.Length+1);
    Console.WriteLine(specific);
    // "elfenliedtopfan5_anims\pubg\m1911"
}
```